# Vapour barrier for basement garage ceiling

Tags: basement, ceiling, garage, vapor-barrier

To make the floor of a bedroom above a garage warmer it is desireable to insulate the garage ceiling.  Does a vapour barrier go up in the joists against the floor above since the house would be expected to be the warm side or between the gyproc and insulation on the garage side since engine heat and meling snow might create a temporary humidity problem?  This is near Calgary where the air, on average, is relatively dry.

Answer (score 1):

The vapor barrier goes towards the heated size of the home, which in your case will be up between the joists against the floor.